# my first steps using BS4 and requests for scraping data and printing to screen

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i am working on a tiny script that fetches data from a web-page and prints them to the screen - using python, beautiful soup and requests:

the page - my base_url = "https://themanifest.com/in/web-development/wordpress/companies?page="

here my steps: first i take care for the import of all the necessary libraries: in my case the following ones: BeautifulSoup and requests.
then i define the base URL and the number of pages we want to scrape.
afterwards i create a for loop that will iterate through each page and extract the relevant information; here i use the requests library to fetch the HTML content of each page. i use Beautiful Soup to parse the HTML content and extract the relevant information. afterwards i store the extracted data in a data structure such as a list or dictionary. i will take care that we repeat steps 4-6 for each page. Once all pages have been scraped, i will take care that we process and analyze the collected data as needed.

Here's my first step towards this goal: how to scrape the web pages from the provided resource:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define the base URL and number of pages to scrape
base_url = "https://themanifest.com/in/web-development/wordpress/companies?page="
num_pages = 10

# Create an empty list to store the scraped data
data = []

# Loop through each page and extract the relevant information
for page_num in range(1, num_pages+1):
    # Fetch the HTML content of the page
    url = base_url + str(page_num)
    response = requests.get(url)
    html_content = response.content
    
    # Parse the HTML content using Beautiful Soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    
    # Extract the relevant information from the page
    company_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'company__list-item'})
    for company in company_list:
        name = company.find('h3', {'class': 'company__list-item__name'}).text
        location = company.find('div', {'class': 'company__list-item__location'}).text
        services = [service.text for service in company.find_all('span', {'class': 'badge__name'})]
        rating = company.find('span', {'class': 'rating__value'}).text
        
        # Store the extracted data in a dictionary and add it to the list
        data.append({'Name': name, 'Location': location, 'Services': services, 'Rating': rating})

# Print the collected data
print(data)
```

BTW: well i guess that we can use pandas as well - alltogehter i guess that there are many options that are smarter than my choice -

what do you say!?

what do you think about the pandas-method - using pandas here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Define the base URL and number of pages to scrape
base_url = "https://themanifest.com/in/web-development/wordpress/companies?page="
num_pages = 10

# Create empty lists to store the scraped data
names = []
locations = []
services = []
ratings = []

# Loop through each page and extract the relevant information
for page_num in range(1, num_pages+1):
    # Fetch the HTML content of the page
    url = base_url + str(page_num)
    response = requests.get(url)
    html_content = response.content
    
    # Parse the HTML content using Beautiful Soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    
    # Extract the relevant information from the page
    company_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'company__list-item'})
    for company in company_list:
        name = company.find('h3', {'class': 'company__list-item__name'}).text
        location = company.find('div', {'class': 'company__list-item__location'}).text
        services_list = company.find_all('span', {'class': 'badge__name'})
        services_str = ', '.join([service.text for service in services_list])
        rating = company.find('span', {'class': 'rating__value'}).text
        
        # Append the extracted data to the respective lists
        names.append(name)
        locations.append(location)
        services.append(services_str)
        ratings.append(rating)

# Create a pandas DataFrame from the scraped data
data = {'Name': names, 'Location': locations, 'Services': services, 'Rating': ratings}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Well; This code creates four separate lists for each of the data points we want to extract, and then combines them into a pandas DataFrame using a dictionary. The resulting DataFrame has four columns corresponding to the data points we extracted, and each row represents a company from the scraped web pages.

i am musing about the best method to go...

Comment: *the best method to go...* leads to opinion based answers: However, I would not use the version with the many individual `list`s unless it is ensured that they are all of the same length. The `dictionary`, on the other hand, has the charming advantage that the missing values can simply be ignored or filled with 'NaN' when converting to a `dataframe`.

Comment: hi there - many thanks for your reply and for sharing your opinion. Awesome! Your ideas are just great! Thanks alot

Comment: well i try to find out which method is the most approipate.